# Why do my spark executors continuously start and exit?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run a simple Python script on my standalone Spark cluster. The cluster has one node running `bin/start-master.sh`, and two nodes running `bin/start-slave.sh`. Looking at the Spark UI on the master node, I can see that the master can see the workers. Here is my little Python test script:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

def add_three(num: int):
    return num + 3

print("Initializing spark context....")
sc = SparkContext(appName="test.py")

arr = [x for x in range(1000)]
print(f'Initial array: {arr}')
res = (sc.parallelize(arr)
         .map(lambda x: add_three(x))
         .collect())
print(f'Transformed array: {res}')
sc.stop()
```

I run this on a separate node with the command:

`bin/spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 test.py`

This kicks things off and I can see the application in my master's UI. In the output, the initial array is printed, but then there is a continuous stream of workers exiting and starting. Here are the master's logs:

```
2018-08-31 21:23:12 INFO  Master:54 - I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
2018-08-31 21:23:18 INFO  Master:54 - Registering worker 10.1.2.93:38905 with 1 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
2018-08-31 21:23:20 INFO  Master:54 - Registering worker 10.1.1.107:36421 with 1 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
2018-08-31 21:25:51 INFO  Master:54 - Registering app test.py
2018-08-31 21:25:51 INFO  Master:54 - Registered app test.py with ID app-20180831212551-0000
2018-08-31 21:25:52 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20180831212551-0000/0 on worker worker-20180831212319-10.1.1.107-36421
2018-08-31 21:25:52 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20180831212551-0000/1 on worker worker-20180831212318-10.1.2.93-38905
2018-08-31 21:25:53 INFO  Master:54 - Removing executor app-20180831212551-0000/0 because it is EXITED
2018-08-31 21:25:53 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20180831212551-0000/2 on worker worker-20180831212319-10.1.1.107-36421
2018-08-31 21:25:55 INFO  Master:54 - Removing executor app-20180831212551-0000/2 because it is EXITED
2018-08-31 21:25:55 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20180831212551-0000/3 on worker worker-20180831212319-10.1.1.107-36421
2018-08-31 21:25:55 INFO  Master:54 - Removing executor app-20180831212551-0000/1 because it is EXITED
2018-08-31 21:25:55 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20180831212551-0000/4 on worker worker-20180831212318-10.1.2.93-38905
2018-08-31 21:25:56 INFO  Master:54 - Removing executor app-20180831212551-0000/3 because it is EXITED
2018-08-31 21:25:56 INFO  Master:54 - Launching executor app-20180831212551-0000/5 on worker worker-20180831212319-10.1.1.107-36421
```

I know this works when, in my pyspark script, I use `SparkContext("local", "test.py")`. None of the driver logs or the executor logs seem to have any errors so I don't have leads on what's going wrong, but they all constantly scroll through launching and removing the executor.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with `sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()`

Comment: Tried changing to `sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()` but it looks like I'm getting the same type of logs (repeatedly launching and removing executors) :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out it was a networking problem. I was running my spark workers, master, and driver in separate docker containers and needed to expose ports between them. In particular, the ports for `spark.driver.port`, `spark.ui.port`, and `spark.blockManager.port`. I was able to get things working by following the dockerfile and run scripts in this repo: https://github.com/tashoyan/docker-spark-submit

Thanks!